# sftp shell script automatic file transfer

Tags: bash, shell

Below script transfered file to another server without password, but after sftp process below statement not executing. also if i run the same script (kept under the ftpAutomatic() ) function under the main (shell script) and calling it inside the case statement , i am getting error as "line 441: syntax error: unexpected end of file
"

## Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

        ftp_site="10.***.***.**"
        username="dwadmin"
#source path
        spath="/home/abc/data"
#Remote Path
        rpath="/home/def/bas"

        cd $spath

        sftp $username@$ftp_site <<EOL
        cd $rpath
        mput bcs_extract_*.txt.pgp
        bye
        EOL
        echo "Success : $?"
        mv $spath/bcs_extract* $spath/queue/
```

## echo "Script done..."

here I didn't get echo "success status?" , "Script done" and "mv" commands not working...but file transfer is done successfully. however this file transfer also not working if i do this script as a function in the main script and calling from "case" statement.

Comment: please tell me the error in my script as above

Comment: Why not just use `scp`?

Comment: Your `EOL` is indented. It shouldn't be. May I recommend using http://www.shellcheck.net?

Comment: You have a problem here that could be related to the indentation of your script -- but your post's markup is off as well, making it difficult to tell how your script is *really* indented (spaces, tabs, not at all?) and what's an artifact of your post. Please edit your post to reflect your actual script.

Comment: I think my sftp not exit and come back to shell "bye" not working, i tried with "quit", "exit" too but no luck

Comment: @user3321778 *Is* the `EOL` line indented or not?

Comment: excellent Biffen.. Thank you so much.. its related to the indented error.

Comment: this tool http://www.shellcheck.net/ corrected my errors in the code.. Have a nice day

Comment: @user3321778, since your problem is solved, please consider closing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

        ftp_site="10.***.***.**"
        username="dwadmin"
#source path
        spath="/home/abc/data"
#Remote Path
        rpath="/home/def/bas"

        cd $spath

        sftp $username@$ftp_site <<-EOF
        cd $rpath
        mput bcs_extract_*.txt.pgp
        exit
        EOF
        echo "Success : $?"
        mv $spath/bcs_extract* $spath/queue/
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to indicate how this is different from the original script, and how the change fixes the problem?

Comment: @Kenster, the `<<-` (vs `<<`) is the obvious change, since it allows the `EOF` sigil to be recognized if tab-indented. However, that only works if leading indentation is tabs, not spaces, so it's definitely something that calls for explanation (and is not a useful answer without same).